# How to superimpose two identical dataframes and adjust values accordingly?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two identical sized dataframes: one dataframe with values and NAs assigned to certain columns and another dataframe where there are 0s and NAs. Essentially, my goal is to look through cells in first dataframe and if there is NA, I want to refer to exact same position in second dataframe and replace it if necessary. Hopefully below example might help explain my situation:

DF1:

| ID | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | **NA** | 45.5 |
| B | 20 | NA |
| C | NA | 14.5 |
| D | **NA** | NA |
| E | 9 | **NA** |

DF2:

| ID | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | NA |
| C | NA | 0 |
| D | 0 | NA |
| E | 0 | 0 |

Desired output:

| ID | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | **0** | 45.5 |
| B | 20 | NA |
| C | NA | 14.5 |
| D | **0** | NA |
| E | 9 | **0** |

Essentially, since the NA in df1 have 0 counterparts in df2, I want them replaced with 0.

```
DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), Var1=c("NA","20","NA","NA","9"), Var2=c("45.50","NA","14.50","NA","NA"))

DF2 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), Var1=c("0","0","NA","0","0"), Var2=c("0","NA","0","NA","0"))
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing NA in dataframe by values in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340350/replacing-na-in-dataframe-by-values-in-other-dataframe)

Comment: You need to change your "NA" character into real `NA` first (`DF1 %>% mutate(across(-ID, ~ifelse(.x == "NA", NA, .x)))`, the same for `DF2`), then use `DF1[is.na(DF1)] <- DF2[is.na(DF1)]` from the dup link